# React display/navigate through JSON back and forward

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm new to React, and I have a JSON data that I want to navigate through and display.

I created a file called `util.js` as follow :

```
const myJson = () => {
  return [
    {
      directors: {
        d_job_1: ["responsability_1", "responsability_2", "responsability_3"],
        d_job_2: {
          d_job_2_1: ["resp_1", "resp_2"],
          d_job_2_2: ["resp_1", "resp_2"],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      hr: [
        {
          hr_job_1: ["resp_1", "resp_2"],
        },
        {
          hr_job_2: ["resp_1", "resp_1"],
        },
        {
          hr_job_3: {
            hr_job_3_1: ["resp_1"],
            hr_job_3_2: ["resp_1"],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    { /* etc.. */},
  ];
};

export default myJson;
```

For this example I need to display a sidebar containing all the main jobs titles (directors, hr, etc..) and when I click on the `directors` for example, I need it to display a component with the directors jobs (`d_job_1`, `d_job_2`), and then if I click on `d_job_1` I'll display the different responsibilities for that job (resp1, resp2), or if I clicked on `d_job_2` it will display more sub jobs (`d_job_2_1`, `d_job_2_2`) and then display the responsibilities when I click on one of them.. I also need to have a `back` button so I can navigate back to where I was.

- Can you give me an idea of how can I manage this kind of logic?
- Do I need to loop through and search the entire JSON every time I click on anything?
- I can add more key data to the JSON if you have an advice for me that requires that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the first hurdle here is the *not very usable* data structure/format. If you could refactor it to something more uniform, reusable components would be possible. For example, currently, if the app state should show the directors jobs, you'd need code that explicitly checks for keys in a given object. Whereas for `hr` it's an array of objects with arbitrary keys.

Comment: @Yoshi The data will change from job to job. There will be more job titles in the JSON later, and each job title can have different nested sub jobs, and finally at the last level there will be a simple array which contains a list of responsibilities as I displayed above. What do you think?

Comment: That might be a start. But in general, you don't want *magic* information in your property keys. It makes iteration or reasoning unnecessary hard. Go for property names that describe what that property holds and use arrays for actual lists. Something like the following maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/2tque1as/

Comment: @Yoshi Oh I understand, thanks that was a great help!

Comment: @Yoshi Using the array you suggested, let's say I navigated to the responsibilities of `Job2`, what do you think it's the best way to be able to go back a level (using a back button for example) and displaying the job titles again (`Job1`, `Job2`)?

Comment: If you will use react router, then do proper url navigation, otherwise pass a function from the parent component to the child component that, handles the back navigation.

Comment: @Yoshi I see, thanks a ton!